# Codeigniter - the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

For the last couple of days my frustration has grown to new heights. Im trying to do a simple login system in codeigniter and I cant get it to work properly.

when submitting the login form I get the following error:

The requested URL /wishlist/login_controller/login was not found on this server.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>login_controller/login">
<input type="text"placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
<input class="btn btn-primary span2" type="submit" id="sign-in" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Here is my login function in login_controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {


function login() {

    $data['error'] = 0;

    if ($_POST) {

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $email = $this->input->post('email', true);
        $password = $this->input->post('password', true);
        $user = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

        if (!$user) {
            $data['error'] = 1;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user['userID']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('firstname',    $user['firstname']);

            redirect(base_url().'admin_controller');

        }
    }

    $this->load->view('home_view');
}
```

I'm using wampserver on localhost. Here is the url that it tries to access:
localhost/wishlist/login_controller/login

Am I correct in assuming that the first part after base_url() is the controller and the second part is the function in that controller?

A couple of settings from the config folder.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$route['default_controller'] = "site_controller";
```

Comment: Do other pages work? How is your .htaccess set?

Comment: the view loaded by the default controller works just fine. I havent edited my .htaccess file at all so its set to: Deny from all

Comment: What 404 are you getting the Apache one, not styled, nothing or one that looks better (the CI one)? Here, it looks like it's CI's. If it were Apache's then the problem is with the server not CI, i.e. htaccess not configured correctly, index.php missing in the URL, etc.

Comment: I can only see the problem of accessing wrong url, please review my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

please rename your controller from

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
```

to

```
class Login_Controller extends CI_Controller {
```

then you can do

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('login_controller/login'); ?>">
<input type="text"placeholder="E-mail" id="email" name="email">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
<input class="btn btn-primary span2" type="submit" id="sign-in" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

then use this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/wishlist/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and htacees:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wishlist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wishlist/index.php/$1 [L]
```

if it's not enought switch config.php file at line:

```
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

i use AUTO maybe you need QUERY_STRING or REQUEST_URI option

Comment: @user927917 you didn't setted the base_url in your config file, i updated my answer, can you try that please

Comment: updated base_url in my config file to: http://localhost/wishlist/ but im still getting the requested URL was not found on this server

Comment: @user927917 you should check your htaccess and remove the index.php from your config file i'll post it to the answer check

Comment: Tried removing the index.php file and edit the .htaccess file. Still no luck. I find it hard to believe that using a framework is suppose to be this complicated. With the amount of time and energy I have used on CI so far, it would have been faster to just write my code using "normal" php.

Comment: @user927917 well this is strange, i'm sorry i tryed doing all was in my possibility to help you, and i'm sorry you still not fixing , but i think if you are newbie on CI you just have to keep a clean copy of it and just follow the user guide, you'll not have any problems, maybe it's a host or server problem ;)

Comment: I certainly appreciate your time and effort. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Change your login() method to something like user_login as using the same name for class and method is not right if you are not using that method as a constructor .

Try to access your url like this

```
http://localhost/wishlist/index.php/login/user_login
```

as you have not change any stting and not added htaccess file your code should be accesible normally so codeiginter has a pattern of accessing url like

```
http://localhost/folder_name/index.php/controller_name/method_name
```

and it seems your accessing URL is not correct.

Comment: Changed some things:
form is now submitted to base_url()user_controller/login
That controller has an index function which loads the main view. user_controller is also loaded via the routes.php file.
However, the problem still persists... :(

Comment: does your initial problem solved or not, which was accessing url and showing form in it

Comment: Unfortunately my initial problem is remain. Getting the same error

Comment: if you don't give action to your form it will get submitted to same method, you can test it by making <form method="post" action=""> this will work properly, change your method's name to something else than login lets assume your method name is user_login then try to access your url like http://localhost/wishlist/index.php/login/user_login and submit your form it will get submitted with the same method

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems at the same time:

1. Your form points at 'login_controller', while your controller is called 'login' (this has already been answered).
2. You must **not** have a method named in the same way as your controller.

   Such method (unless your class is within a namespace, but that's not the case with CodeIgniter) is executed as the class constructor.

Comment: having method name login is not a problem, it will be consider as constructor, yes but this method will be called two times first while creating class, and once method is called using uri routing

Comment: And that ain't a problem? Plus, at least the latest CodeIgniter version will call `Login::index()` instead of `Login::login()` if you try to do that.

Comment: Have renamed controller to user_controller and kept the name of the login function. That didnt solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You call `action="<?php echo base_url()?>login_controller/login">` when controller's name is `"login"` and `method "login"`.

You need to call 
`base_url('login/login');` 
and sure, set `base_url` in `config.php`, you have index_page setted.

Maybe you dont have `.htaccess`, then you need to call `mysite.com/index.php/login/login/`

Comment: why? i always use this and it's ok

Comment: is the same, the only different is this:

base_url-> This function returns the same thing as site_url, without the index_page or url_suffix being appended.

Comment: uhm sounds strange need to try

Comment: you can read it here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html xD

Comment: @lspuk it is the same as long as you have ModRewrite set up to redirect all traffic  to index.php

Comment: oh ok never used that is problem :) always used site_url()

Comment: @lspuk That's what you should be anyway, but the other one is not wrong in one of many cases...

Comment: @kaseOga so sorry man, thanks for the tip i'll use that for my static resources right now :)

Comment: @jadkik94 sure, but good to know, ever tought base_url() doesn't accepted params :P need to re-read the doc, it's too much time i do not read that :/