# The requested URL /clients/login was not found on this server. Error comes in Codeigniter application

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm fed-up with server configuration.
I have one Codeigniter application that runs very well when I hosted that on shared server. Now I'm trying to host it on my own server, I had made all required changes, and the site's `index.html` file runs properly. But now it gives me an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /clients/login was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

I did not get what is the error in configuration. I've already referred following site:

[laravel the requested url was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242495/laravel-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-requested-url-login-was-not-found-on-this-server?page=1

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

[The requested URL /login was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084695/the-requested-url-login-was-not-found-on-this-server)

[Codeigniter - the requested URL was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543779/codeigniter-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server)

Any kind of help is Welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this would help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492446/codeigniter-2-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-404-error-ci-is?answertab=votes#tab-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492446/codeigniter-2-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-404-error-ci-is?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @krishnaraj I've made changes like that also, but same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be `/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` instead of `/home.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: No, it should be /home.php?/$1 [L,QSA] and not /home.php?$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

my experience :

1. on  :
   Rewrite Rules ^(.*)$ /home.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
   change :`home.php`   to    `index.php`

like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2. in   `application->config->config.php`
   set your   `config.php`   like this :

   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/app_folder/';
   $config['index_page'] = '';

Now access :

```
http://localhost/app_folder/
```

will show you your login page

> Thanks